# Relationship field and dereference a null object problem

Tags: apex, soql

All that I am trying to do is say: SELECT the Department__c WHERE the NAME of the Department__c is equal to the NAME of the Account.Property__c. I am trying to compare string to string.

I keep getting

> "Attempt to dereference a null object"

when I run the code.

```
Property__c prop2 = acc.Property__r;
String propString = prop2.Name;

Departments__c depo;
depo = [SELECT Name, Id FROM Departments__c WHERE Name = :propString];
```

Comment: can you check value of acc.Property__r?

Comment: Your exception message should contain the line where the error is. That will tell you what variable is null. Probably `acc` or `prop2` are null, causing the error. We need a bit more information (the full method text and the exception text)

Comment: acc.Property__r is null for some reason, yet it does exist! @Himanshu

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all thos variables it can work in following way.Update your code in following way.

```
set<id> propertyIds = new set<id>();

//get All the propertyIds
for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
{
  if(acc.Property__c!=null)
     propertyIds.add(acc.property__c)
}

//prepare set of property name
set<String> propName = new set<String>();
for(Property__c prop: [SELECT Name, Id FROM property__c
  WHERE id in :propertyIds])
{
   propName.add(prop.Name);
}

//your deparment list which can be used for rest of the code.
List<Departments__c> depo : [SELECT Name, Id FROM Departments__c
  WHERE Name in : propName];
```

Comment: This removes the error, but it still thinks acc.Property__r.Name equals null...So it just skips the if condition posted above

Comment: that is correct. where are you setting up that value in trigger ?

Comment: I just have----- for (Account acc : Trigger.new) -- (Before insert account trigger)

Comment: From the account I update the property, when I click save, I get an error

Comment: "acc.Property__r.Name" won't throw an exception even if no Property__c value is present, while the original version would, because the magic is lost when the statement ends.

Comment: that is the problem which i initially thought. relationship objects are not available inside trigger so you need to first query the data and then you can get Property__c.Name

Comment: So is there no way to just take the text input from the Property__c field on an Account and store it in a variable? @Himanshu

Comment: i am actually not sure what is your business logic of this trigger but check the updated code in answer. it can give you head start.  I have added some best practices as well to handle bulk data.

Comment: Thanks, but the name just keeps coming back null. Not sure why, the Property__c that I'm referring to definitely has a name. @Himanshu

Comment: first check whether acc.Property__c is null or not by debugging

Comment: I have, it is coming up "null". @Himanshu

Comment: acc.Property__c is it null ?

Comment: Alex, the `__r.Name` property isn't automatically retrieved for you and isn't available in the trigger until you query for it separately. This is why it is null. The only value you have available is the `id` that is in the `__c` lookup field. You do not have immediate access to any related data via `__r.[fieldname]`. If you need to reference these related pieces of data, you must query for them.